# Getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException while creating docker Image which has Gatling

Tags: docker, scala, gatling

I'm trying to create docker Image of my scala project using `sbt-native-packager`.

The project also include `Gatlings load test`.

`Gatlings` load tests are working fine, but when I try to create it's docker image it throw an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`.

here is the detail:

**build.sbt:**

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

ThisBuild / scapegoatVersion := "1.4.8"


lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "face-recognition"
  )

enablePlugins(GatlingPlugin, JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin, ScoverageSbtPlugin)
ocker / packageName := "face-recognition"

Docker / version := "0.0.1"
dockerExposedPorts := Seq(8080)

dockerChmodType := DockerChmodType.UserGroupWriteExecute
dockerPermissionStrategy := DockerPermissionStrategy.CopyChown
dockerAdditionalPermissions += (DockerChmodType.UserGroupPlusExecute, "/var/run/")

Docker / daemonUserUid := None
Docker / daemonUser := "root"

dockerBaseImage := "amazoncorretto:11-alpine3.18-jdk"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.9.1" % "test",
  "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.9.1" % "test",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-slf4j" % "2.8.0",
  "io.gatling" % "gatling-http" % "3.5.1"
)
```

**plugin.sbt:**

```
addSbtPlugin("io.gatling" % "gatling-sbt" % "4.2.6")
```

When I run command `docker:publishLoca` get an **error**:

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run last Gatling-it / enterprisePackage for the full output
[error] (Gatling-it / enterprisePackage) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Couldn't locate Gatling libraries in the classpath
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to run it in docker, it is trying to run with:

```
GatlingIt / enterprisePackage
```

Which is causing the problem, because you have added simple library dependencies:

```
"io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.9.1" % "test",
  "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.9.1" % "test"
```

Above dependencies are with `"test"` which works fine for simple `Gatling / enterprisePackage` (or in sbt 0.13 `gatling:test`). Now you need to add `"it"` in dependencies. Your updated dependencies are:

```
"io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.9.1" % "test,it",
      "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.9.1" % "test,it"
```

Now these dependencies will add libraries for `GatlingIt` and you will be able to make image.

I hope above answer will work for you.